# How to get Elasticsearch query return different results when using different port

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ES cluster and five department use it. But I need to make them query data only belongs to themselves. I want to query by five ports to be a top priority.

Let's say I have one cluster and created five indices. So ES just return A.index's results when A.dep query data. I read ES documentation and some blog, but still don't know how to get what I want.

I have two options:

1. Multiple ports query data;
2. use user permission control query.

How to get what I want? I am new to ES.

Comment: Could you just run five separate instances of Elasticsearch?

Comment: Like multiple instances on a computer? Unified management through a cluster？